# Accessibility Identifier Generation

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Certain testing and UI libraries require accessibility identifiers to be set for UI components in storyboards or xibs. I'd like to convert an entire project with some convention like using the mapped property name for the identifier, but anything would be useful. Is there a way to automatically generate accessibility identifiers for xib/storyboard defined views in a project?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out an efficient way of doing this? I'm facing the same situation right now and I'm looking around to see how people may have solved this.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in Xcode so I think you'd have to write a small script or program to manipulate the plist files directly.

Another alternative is to set the identifiers programatically. You could write a helper function to walk the view hierarchy and for any elements where an accessibility label is set, set the identifier (using whatever convention you like), this would be called from `viewDidLoad`.